# Python not able to import any module

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, sdk

I don't know whether I've just installed them wrong or there's another problem. I installed the ebay sdk but whenever I try to import it I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebaysdk'
```

Are there any common problems with this I could check for a solution? It shouldn't be the code as I copied it from the example code off the website.

Thanks for any help.

P.S I'm using 3.6

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re running into this problem for _all_ modules? Can you share some info on your dev environment?

Comment: Did you install this package with pip? If you have multiple versions of python installed, it can be easy to get lost.  For example, you may have `pip` `pip3` `pip3.6` etc.. all installed on your machine. Make sure the pip you are using matches the version of python you are actually running your code with

Comment: questions regarding errors from code should contain the relevant code snippet so we can attempt to reproduce the error. otherwise the question is too broad. edit your question and include the relevant code.

Comment: @davedwards this is a question about environment, not code.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik great, i'm glad you understand the question much better than i do. i will stay out and let you resolve the solution.

Comment: "_I installed the ebay sdk_": How did you install the ebay sdk? What was the _exact_ command/s you used to install, and what are the commands you use now to run the script/code. The Python version/environment you used to install must also be the same one you use to run the code.

Comment: @davedwards I might not, but out of context canned responses are the cancer of SO. They show writer's laziness and disrespect to OP. Please don't use them that way.